# Downloaded iOS Distribution certificate not under 'My Certificates'

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

I download an iOS Distribution certificate from my company, and store the `.cer` file in my Downloads folder. I double click on it, and the Keychain Access opens. On the left side, I see the categories `My Certificates` and `Certificates`. The certificate is added to the latter category. How can I make it appear also in `My Certificates`? Copy and Paste does not work.

I see I am not the only one with this problem: it has also been asked on the [Apple discussion forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3232847), but does not have an answer yet.

Related to that, when I click in the XCode Preferences, in the Accounts Tab, on View Details, I only see iOS Development in Signing Identities. With the certificate I just downloaded, I expect a few more identities. Is this related to the `My Certificates` question? If not, how do I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That probably means that the certificate was not generated from you machine.

**1. Ask the person who have created the distribution certificate to export .p12 file of certificate.**

To export the certificate right click on it and then hit export. It will ask for the password enter a strong password.

**2.When you receive that certificate click on it will ask for the password, enter the password which was entered while exporting the .p12 file.**

Comment: That was indeed it! Thanks for your quick and exact help.